# How to assign triggers to variables in C#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, variables, triggers

When coding in Visual Basic, I'm able to define triggers to variables like: Whenever the value of the variable is changed, this triggers a function, which in turn changes the value of another variable. I wonder if there is a way to do the same in C#; that is, I want to define a trigger to a variable, fired every time when the value of that variable is changed.

Below code is how I do it in VB. When running this App, whenever a new user logs in, the App assigns the username like `ActiveUserName = "SomeUserName"`, and this in turn automatically updates the `FormMain.StatusLabelUserName.Text` in the form. So, is there a way to achieve this trigger in C#?

```
Public Property ActiveUserName() As String
    Get
        ActiveUserName = FormMain.StatusLabelUserName.Text
    End Get
    Set(ByVal Value As String)
        FormMain.StatusLabelUserName.Text = Value
    End Set
End Property
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you're looking for `Properties`

```
private int localMember;
public int publicProperty
{
  get
  {
    return localMember;
  }
  set
  {
    localMember = value;
    //Do whatever you want here.
  }
}
```

The "get" block is run any time you access the value.  The "set" block is run any time you assign a value.

Comment: Just a quick addition; the feature the OP wants can be accomplished by raising and event inside the setter; which the framework registers for with a binding (WPF only of course).

Comment: BTW, `value` is a special keyword for use in the set block.  It contains the assigned value.

Answer (score 1):

This is handled by raising events. This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2246777/raise-an-event-whenever-a-propertys-value-changed) describes how to do it well.

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple [**property**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9fsa0sw.aspx). Here's the C# syntax:

```
public string ActiveUserName
{
    get { return FormMain.StatusLabelUserName.Text; }
    set { FormMain.StatusLabelUserName.Text = value; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Properties can work the same in C#

```
public string ActiveUserName
{
  get{ return FormMain.StatusLabelUserName.Text;}
  set{FormMain.StatusLabelUserName.Text = value; /*do more stuff here; */}
}
```

This can get rather messy and somewhat rigid however.  You may consider using events to accomplish the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Use INotifyPropertyChanged event.

Answer (score -1):

Properties and the set brackets.
INotifyPropertyChanged could be implemented for WPF databindings for exemple.