# How to create a property changed event when the property has only a getter in C#

Tags: c#, events, inotifypropertychanged, propertychanged

Let's say I have this class (which is really for demonstration purposes):

```
class Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string IdNumber { get; set; }

    // CheckPopulationRegistry() checks against the database if a person
    // these exact properties (FirstName, LastName, IdNumber etc.) exists.
    public bool IsRealPerson => CheckPopulationRegistry(this);
}
```

I want to be notified when `IsRealPerson` is changed.

Usually, I would implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface, but then I'd need to [create an `OnIsRealPersonChanged()` method, and call it from the setter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2246837/1925272), which I do not have.

Ideas?

Comment: Whatever logic is changing output of CheckPopulationRegistry(), raise the PropertyChanged event from there before returning out of the method.

Comment: _need to create an OnIsRealPersonChanged()_ - that's unusual. The norm is just an  `OnPropertyChanged(string propertyname)`.

Comment: set
            {
                IsRealPerson = value;
                CallSomeMethod();
            }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need something like this:

```
public class Person : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string firstName;
    private string lastName;

    private void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    private bool CheckPopulationRegistry(Person p)
    {
        // TODO:
        return false;
    }

    public string FirstName
    {
        get { return firstName; }
        set
        {
            if (firstName != value)
            {
                firstName = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(IsRealPerson));
            }
        }
    }

    public string LastName
    {
        get { return lastName; }
        set
        {
            if (lastName != value)
            {
                lastName = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(IsRealPerson));
            }
        }
    }

    // IdNumber is omitted

    public bool IsRealPerson => CheckPopulationRegistry(this);

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

}
```