# Add Property to an existing class in a library

Tags: c#, wpf, oop

I want to add a Property to the Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.Folder class.
The reason for this is, I need a bool Property "Selected" to bind it in WPF to a checkbox.

First I thought I can use C#-Extensions but currently it's not possible to write a property extension.

Then I created my own class "MyFolder" so I can cast from the Folder class to my class.

It doesn't work either.

```
public class MyFolder : Folder, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private bool selected;

    public bool Selected
    {
        get { return selected; }
        set { selected = value; OnPropertyChanged("Selected"); }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public MyFolder(ExchangeService service):base(service)
    {

    }

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
    }
}
```

**Edit:**

I know it would be possible to add a property Folder to the class MyFolder. But I thought it must be possible in a elegant way.

```
public class MyFolder : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private bool selected;

    public bool Selected
    {
        get { return selected; }
        set { selected = value; OnPropertyChanged("Selected"); }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public Folder FolderObject { get; set; }

    public MyFolder(Folder FolderObject)
    {
        this.FolderObject = FolderObject;
    }

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you using `Folder` or `MyFolder` in your code?

Comment: MyFolder is the class I want to work with, because MyFolder has the selected property.

Comment: I understand that but you said you have to cast `Folder` to `MyFolder`. That's why I'm asking if you are using `Folder` or `MyFolder` in your code.

Comment: I'm using MyFolder

Comment: Have you look at this question [2246777](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2246777/raise-an-event-whenever-a-propertys-value-changed)

Comment: you should wrap the class your trying to bind to in a View model and then you can add the selected property to the view model class see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/hh848246.aspx

Comment: @MikeT That's a good way, but currently I'm not using MVVM. I will remember it in future. Thanks!

Comment: your MyFolder class as shown in the edit is a viewmodel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to add a property to an existing class.
As you are in MVVM, why not simply implement a View Model that represents that functionality.

So for example:

```
class MyFolderViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public bool IsSelected { get; set; }

    private Folder folderObject;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Thats a good way, but I am not using MVVM. I will remember it in future!

Comment: Generally you use MVVM. Your class `MyFolder` acts as a View Model since it implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`. What do you want to achieve with `MyFolder`?

Answer (score 1):

> I want to add a Property to the `Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.Folder` class.

This is indeed not possible since you haven't defined this class yourself and thus you cannot change its definition. Adding a property to a class would require you to recompile it.

> Then I created my own class "MyFolder" so I can cast from the Folder class to my class.

You cannot cast a `Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.Folder` object to a custom type of yours...this will never work.

What you should do is to create your own class, e.g. `MyFolder`, that wraps any functionality of the `Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.Folder` class that you need. This is basically what you have done already I guess. There is no better way.

You then bind directly to an instance of your client-aware class (`MyFolder`) that implements the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface. This is a good and recommended approach really. Forget about adding properties to a build-in class and casting.

Comment: And how can I convert an existing Folder object to a MyFolder object?

Comment: You can't convert it. You should wrap it in your custom class. Then you can simply bind to Folder.SomeProperty of your MyFolder object.

Comment: @Waterfront you can't cast Folder into myFolder however you can set up an implicit or Explixt converter that will allow you to convert see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/implicit