# What is the best way to trigger events based on changes made to database tables?

Tags: c#

Is there a better way than the below to detect if the value retrieved from a database is different to the last retrieved value?

I have a feeling that something better than in infinite poll is available out there?

```
public void CheckForNewMofificationDate(string username)
{
    while(true)
    {
        OdbcConnection sql = null;
        if (!DBClass.Instance.OpenConn(ref sql))
            throw new DatabaseConnectionException();
        try
        {
            string query = "SELECT MODIFIED_ON FROM USER_DTLS WHERE USERNAME=?";
            using (var cmd = new OdbcCommand(query, sql))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.Add("USERNAME", OdbcType.VarChar, 50).Value = username;
                using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    if (reader.Read())
                    {

                        if( OldValue != reader.GetString(0))
                        {
                            //use INotifyPropertyChange
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            DBClass.Instance.CloseConn(ref sql);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How is this value updated? If you don't have code yet and your question is how to get an event if a value in the database has changed, you can use [`SqlDependency`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/detecting-changes-with-sqldependency) (presuming sql-server).

Comment: Please post some code you tried to write.

Comment: @TimSchmelter The value will have to be retrieved from a database.

Comment: Google `INotifyPropertyChanged` and learn from there

Comment: Is this "variable" a class property? Take a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2246777/raise-an-event-whenever-a-propertys-value-changed

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto: the property doesn't change but a value in the database. I guess he wants to update this property then, but the question is how  to know  when to update without constantly requesting the database. Is that correct @Abs?

Comment: @TimSchmelter Something has to update the variable in the code, it won't automagically get the value from the database, will it?

Comment: @TimSchmelter Yes that is exactly may question!

Comment: @Abs: then look at my first comment and try `SqlDependency`. It might be what you are looking for.

Comment: @TimSchmelter I think this is the best solution to employ, please add as an answer for me to accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As recommended by @TimSchmelter, A [SqlDependancy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/detecting-changes-with-sqldependency) is the best approach I found so far, it causes Sql Server to detect changes made to tables assoiciated with a query and fire events based on that:

> A SqlDependency object can be associated with a SqlCommand in order to
>   detect when query results differ from those originally retrieved. You
>   can also assign a delegate to the OnChange event, which will fire when
>   the results change for an associated command. You must associate the
>   SqlDependency with the command before you execute the command. The
>   HasChanges property of the SqlDependency can also be used to determine
>   if the query results have changed since the data was first retrieved.

This eliminates the need to have a serprate thread with an infinite loop continuasslt polling to detect changes.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: you would have to employ a polling (looping) mechanism like you suggested.

Or, you could do something crazy with triggers on the database and have the trigger execute a custom function or web service that uses an event bus or WCF to notify your application of a change in data, but I would highly recommend *not* pursuing this approach.