# What is the best way to trigger a change in C#?

Tags: c#, events, methods, triggers, event-handling

I have a variable

```
double total = 25;
```

I want `event()` to happen whenever total changes.

How do I monitor and cause event() to happen when total changes?
For example, when total goes from 1 to 2, event happens, then when total goes from 2 to 3, event gets triggered again.

Edit. this is a variable, no I cannot make it into a property.

Thanks, I'm still learning.

Comment: Is total a field or a local variable?

Comment: If you can make Total a property, you can use this method to raise then event when the property changes: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2246777/raise-an-event-whenever-a-propertys-value-changed

Comment: This seems a little broad. Is this variable a class field or property? Does the class expose events already? What specifically are you stuck on?

Comment: http://www.shenchauhan.com/blog/2018/6/18/fody-inotifypropertychanged-the-easy-way

Comment: total is a variable, it changes at different times

Comment: Check out reactive extensions: https://github.com/dotnet/reactive

Comment: It's a variable? OK, then the thing changing it will have to trigger the event.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Raise an event whenever a property's value changed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2246777/raise-an-event-whenever-a-propertys-value-changed)

Comment: I only have access to the variable.

Comment: @Olivier It's a local variable.

Comment: There isn't a magic bullet here. You can't just subscribe to changes on a local variable. You'll need to fire the events at the same time as you set the value.

Comment: `this is a variable, no I cannot make it into a property.` Create a new `Bob` class with a `double` property. Use `INotifyPropertyChanged` in the setter of the property. Change your local variable to be of type `Bob`.

Comment: @babavic Impossible : you need to use an embedded value like mjwills said. You can create a generic for that, like `EmbeddedValue<T>` with change and triggering events and all you need.